# Unwanted character in CSV file when serializing from QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtextstream, qdatastream

I am trying to read data from a `QTableWidget`, and save them in a CSV file.

The values saved in the file are correct, but for the first column in every row there is an unwanted character in the beginning.

Here is my code:

```
void Task::on_button_Export_clicked()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,tr("Export Task List"), "",tr("CSV Files (*.csv)"));
    if (fileName.isEmpty())
            return;
    else
    {
        QFile file(fileName);
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        {
            QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Unable to open file"),
            file.errorString());
            return;
        }
        QDataStream out(&file);
        out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_4);
        int rowCount = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
        int colCount = ui->tableWidget->columnCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
         {
            QString str(QString::null);

           /* if (i > 0)
            {
               str = "\n";
            }*/

            for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
            {
               if (j > 0)
               {
                  str += ",";
               }
               QTableWidgetItem* item = ui->tableWidget->item(i,j);
               str += item->data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
            }
            str += "\n";
            out << str;
         }
    }
}
```

The saved file looks like this:

```
ÎDPC Task
ÞMain Task
ÌWorkLoop
ÐWorkLoop
ÌIST0
ÊIST1
ÆIST2
```

I am using Qt 5.4.0.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `QString str(QString::null);` - what is this? Just write `QString str;`. By the way, there are `QTextStream` class for building strings.

Comment: I tried String str first. My guess was that it was getting some garbag value so later changed it to QString str(QString::null) to initialize it with null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else` in the beginning is useless if you use `return` to ends execution of the function (you didn't use `else` in the second test).

If you need to write text, you should use a [`QTextStream`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html) instead of a `QDataStream` which is designed to read/write binary data.

Why using a temporary `QString` in you loops? You have a stream, use it:

```
void Task::on_button_Export_clicked() {
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(
        this,tr("Export Task List"), "",tr("CSV Files (*.csv)")
    );
    if (fileName.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Unable to open file"),
        file.errorString());
        return;
    }

    QTextStream out(&file);
    int rowCount = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
    int colCount = ui->tableWidget->columnCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        /* if (i > 0) {
            out << "\n";
        }*/
        for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
            if (j > 0) {
                out << ",";
            }
            QTableWidgetItem* item = ui->tableWidget->item(i,j);
            out << item->data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
        }
        out << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked and giving me the correct result now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `QDataStream` for saving text files. Use `QTextStream`. `QDataStream` use it's own serialization format instead of writing plain text.

For strings, first two bytes is length, then it's content (2 bytes per char). Your "garbage" is a length of each string. You see only one char, because your file is in unicode.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. You are right in saying that garbage was actually the length of each string.